# Apply hover over all list items, except one that is specified

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

In Angular 2+, is there any way of stopping the hover CSS function on an item of a list, as specified by the Angular code?

I have a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ktaky3) here to show a simple example what I am talking about.

I am using the `ngClass` feature to apply style dynamically to whichever list item is selected at the time, as this will change (only one item will be selected at any one time).

```
<ul>
  <li id="{{item.name}}" *ngFor="let item of list" [ngClass]="{disableThis: item.selected}">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

I have looked into the :not() feature of CSS application, however I could not find a way of getting this to work with data interpolation.

ie:

```
.myElement:hover:not({{listItem.name}}) {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: The selector should be `.myElement:not(.disableThis):hover {`. Assuming that `myElement` class is applied to all `li` elements.

Comment: @Tushar - You're kidding? It was that easy!?

Comment: @physicsboy Tushar is correct, updated stackblitz is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qhtykw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**app.component.ts**

```
  items = {
    name: 'name',
    lang: ['php', 'javascript', 'angular']
  };
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ul>
 <li id="{{item.name}}" class="items" *ngFor="let item of items.lang">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

**app.component.css or app.component.scss**

```
// 1
.items:not(:first-of-type):hover {
  color: red;
}

// 2
.items:not(:last-of-type):hover {
  color: red;
}

// 3
.items:not(:first-child):hover {
  color: red;
}

// 4
.items:not(:last-child):hover {
  color: red;
}

// 5 by index of item
.items:not(:nth-child(2)):hover {
  color: red;
}

// 6 by index of item
.items:not(:nth-child(3)):hover {
  color: red;
}
```

---

### By selector Id

---

**app.component.ts**

```
items = [
    {
      id: 'php',
      lang: 'php'
    },
    {
      id: 'angular',
      lang: 'angular'
    },
    {
      id: 'css',
      lang: 'css'
    }
  ];
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ul>
    <li id="{{ item.id }}" class="items" *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.lang}}</li>
</ul>
```

**app.component.css or app.component.scss**

```
.items:not(#angular):hover {
  color: red;
}

// Or
.items:not(#php):hover {
  color: red;
}

// Or
.items:not(#css):hover {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If stopping hover depends on particular element having class `disableThis` attached, you only have to modify your css like this:

```
.disableThis,
.disableThis:hover {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tushar won the day with a quick comment to say:

> The selector should be .myElement:not(.disableThis):hover {. Assuming that myElement class is applied to all li elements.

This worked for me and also in my larger project that I was extracting the code from.